# Sort order of BigQueryStorage Read API

Tags: api, google-bigquery, storage

As the title states, is there any sort order for the data read using the read streams constructed with the Storage Read API? Is there any ordering with respect to partitions and clustering keys, as I understand partitions are colocated and if clustering is used, the data in a partition is stored in clustered blocks?

Answer (score 0):

### For the 1st Question

Storage API operates on [storage directly](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/storage#key_features).Thus you really can’t make assumptions regarding in which order you will receive the data by using Storage Read API.

### For the 2nd Question

In a clustered table the data gets automatically organized whenever new data is added to a table or specific partition.From the [partitioned table doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables) and [clustered table doc](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables)

> **Partition table:** A partitioned table is a special table that is divided into segments, called partitions, that make it easier to manage and query your data. 
>
> **Cluster table:**  When you create a clustered table in BigQuery the table data is automatically organized based on the contents of one or more columns in the table's schema. The columns you specify are used to collocate related data. When data is written to a clustered table, BigQuery sorts the data using the values in the clustering columns. 
> These values are used to organize the data into multiple blocks in BigQuery storage. The order of clustered columns determines the sort order of the data. When new data is added to a table or a specific partition, BigQuery performs automatic re-clustering in the background to restore the sort property of the table or partition.

When you are using `cluster by` with some columns , it gets applied to the whole dataset. If the table is a `partitioned table` then it will be applied to each partition.

You can follow this [code lab](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/gcp-bq-partitioning-and-clustering#5) for a better understanding. From the lab:-
Consider this `stackoverflow.question_2018` table as an example. Let's assume it has 3 columns

1. Creation_date    2.Title     3.Tags

If we create a new partitioned table from the main table having `creation_date` as date partition , then as per partitioning logic it will have a partition for every creation date.
[image]

Now if we create a table `creation_date` as a partition and apply `cluster by` on column `tags` then clustering will be applied to each of the  partitions. Even if we add new data in this table , bigquery will take care of reorganizing the data.

[image]
Hope this helps you to understand.

Comment: I am bringing up the question once more. I have been doing some experimentation recently with the BigQuery Storage API. The rows returned seems to be in the (approximate) order based on the clustered fields as well as the partition. You stated I could not make any assumptions regarding the underlying storage. Yet, from your quote: 
`The columns you specify are used to collocate related data.`
Would not this imply that reading from the Storage API, should return rows in the order defined by the clustering fields and/or partition?

Answer (score 0):

Storage Read API can return data in multiple streams. Depending on how the data from each stream are put together, the final result may or may not preserve the original order

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).